# Inserting HTML options alphabetically into ordered text file via PHP

Tags: php, html, sorting

I'm looking for a method to alphabetically insert lines of code (in the form of HTML option elements) into an already-sorted list file through PHP.

Here is an example of the format of each element in the list:

```
<option value="21">Kevin</option>
```

Using PHP, can I insert the new option by using that string in between the opening and ending option tags? Something like whatever string exists between `>` and `</`? I am not sure of how I can get this accomplished with PHP.

Is there a simpler method that just inserts the new option at the top of the list and evokes a sorting function?

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You might be better suited doing this with javascript/jquery

Comment: yes, you can. use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) to tear apart the html.

Comment: Parse the file using the DOM library, make an array out of all the options, and add your new elements to that array. Then use `usort()` to sort it based on the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using PHP array. You can store values in PHP array and print like follows.

```
<?php
$opt_val = array(1=>"name 2",2=>"name 1",3=>"name 3");
asort($opt_val);

foreach($opt_val as $key=>$val)
{
   echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$val.'</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: @DatapawWolf: is this answer helping you?

Comment: I will give it a shot as soon as I can. Thanks!